# How do I include the separate codemirror mode files using bower?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp, bower, codemirror

I'm building an angular fullstack application using Yeoman Angular Fullstack, which includes bower.

In that application, I'm using a component called Codemirror, which has its own bower package called `codemirror`, and another bower package called `angular-ui-codemirror`.

Inside of the regular `codemirror` bower package, there are additional mode files in a directory called `mode`, and in a normal non-bower managed application, I'd simply just add the necessary script tags to my `index.html`, but here, i want to do it the correct way using bower, if possible.

How should I include that separate sub-file for the codemirror mode using bower?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since *angular-fullstack* uses *[wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep)* to inject your bower dependencies, you could overrides the `main` property of the *codemirror* bower package to include the additional files you want from its `mode` directory.

To do so, you have two options:

- Override in your `Gruntfile`
- Override directly in your `bower.json`

I'll recommend you the second solution, because at a single look of your manifest file you can see what files will be included, it's more verbose and comprehensible.

Here is an example with the a `bower.json` and including the extra `asterisk.js` file, but it's almost the same using the `Gruntfile` option.

```
{
  "name": "testingPurposes",
  "dependencies": {
    "codemirror": "~4.7.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "codemirror": {
      "main": ["lib/codemirror.js", "lib/codemirror.css", "mode/asterisk/asterisk.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then when running a task that use the `wiredep` one, like `grunt serve`, you will see the additional file included in your `index.html`.

Comment: This worked beautifully with gulp `main-bower-files` also.

Comment: @techmsi Yeah that's almost the same thing, nice to know though :)